# Prove that $\frac{b-a}{\cos^2 (a)}< \tan b - \tan a < \frac{b-a}{\cos^2 b}$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $\frac{b-a}{\cos^2 (a)}< \tan b - \tan a < \frac{b-a}{\cos^2 b}$
where $0 < a < b < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I can't even start solving this. Could you please help me? :D

Comment: i think your inequality is not true

Comment: In the right side must be $cos^2b$

Comment: You're right, sir! :D

Comment: Did someone say Bill $\cos b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $\dfrac{\tan(b)-\tan(a)}{b-a}=\sec^2(c)$.

Now, in $[0,\pi/2)$, $\sec^2(x)$ is an increasing function.

Therefore, $\sec^2(a)<\sec^2(c)<\sec^2(b)$ which shows that $\sec^2(a)<\dfrac{\tan(b)-\tan(a)}{b-a}<\sec^2(b)$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\tan(b) - \tan(a) = \int_a^b \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} \ dx $$
Since $\cos(x)$ is a decreasing function on the interval $(0, \pi / 2)$ then its reciprocal must be an increasing function hence.

$$\frac{b-a}{\cos^2 (a)} < \int_a^b \frac{1}{\cos^2 (x)} \ dx < \frac{b - a}{\cos^2 (b)}$$

and the result follows.